# How to draw a progress bar in JSF application

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, progress-bar

We are having a web application that is built on JEE6 (JSF 2/ EJB 3 / Jboss 7).

There is a need for us to display progress bars like the one below in our application. Which framework can we use? Is there a way to do this thing in Primefaces ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<p:progressBar/>` of PrimeFaces. They have examples of a client-side, ajax and static version at their [showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/progressBar.xhtml).

The ajax version boils down to starting the progressbar on a certain action (commandButton click in the example). It will automatically stopping when 100% is reached (an ajax event is fired then if needed, see the docs)

Relevant xhtml and bean parts of the showcase copied (almost) verbatim

**xhtml**

```
<p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" value="#{progressBarView.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" styleClass="animated" global="false">
    <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{progressBarView.onComplete}" update="growl" oncomplete="PF('startButton2').enable()"/>
</p:progressBar>
```

**bean**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ProgressBarView implements Serializable {

    private Integer progress;

    public Integer getProgress() {
        if(progress == null) {
            progress = 0;
        }
        else {
            progress = progress + (int)(Math.random() * 35);

            if(progress > 100)
                progress = 100;
        }

        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(Integer progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    public void onComplete() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Progress Completed"));
    }
}
```

In the example on the PF showcase, you can also cancel it, but cancelling a real server-side action is out of scope here so I removed that:

Comment: @16num: there is an example on the PF showcase... Easy to find (and you can propose an edit to answer by pressing the edit button beneath it) And this is specifically the reason 'link only answers' are strongly discouraged